# API For Products based on specific Brand - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

How to Get all products belongs to specific Brand for WooCommerce API ? For Category we can use the below API and is working fine.
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=12

I have tried https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?brand=12 for Filtering product with Brand, but its not working.(Have Installed WooCommerce Brand Plugin and Get all Brand API works perfectly fine)

What is the Correct API to this ?

Comment: Try this `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/brand/12`

Comment: Thanks , I fixed the issue by creating my own custom route to query the result. 
Create custom route in any of the end point and in call back function write your logic(SQL query ) and return it .  This documentation helps 
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/